# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null?

Tags: postgresql, javax.imageio

I actually get the input source from PostgreSQL.
The table column type is bytea. I want to convert the byte back to original image.

```
BuffredImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIo.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(rsvalue.getBytes(10)));

ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File("D:\\"+ rsvalue.getString(2) +".jpg"));
```

The error as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1457)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1521)
    at my.lincdoc.controller.ProposalController.RetrieveProposalForm(ProposalController.java:66)
    at my.lincdoc.common.App.main(App.java:16)
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [`ImageIO.read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) state:

> If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

And if `bImageFromConvert` is null, you'll get the exception you've shown. So that's almost certainly what's happening. You should look at the data returned from `rsvalue.getBytes(10)` - see whether it's incomplete, corrupt or something similar. A starting point would be to write it to a file and see whether you can open it using a picture viewer.

Comment: Hi Jon, just wondering how to register ImageReader  ? I'm new to java.

Comment: @Jason: I don't know offhand, but I'd check that the data is correct first. After that, find an ImageIO tutorial :)

Comment: @Jason: Don't just rely on the first *byte* being fetched correctly. Dump the whole thing to a file, and check you can load it. Otherwise you could easily be chasing your tail for ages.

Comment: I use paint to open the file, but hit error "This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format not currently supported"

Comment: While using Windows Photo Viewwer, the error is can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.

Comment: @Jason: Right - so it sounds like you need to fix that before you worry about ImageIO :) See whether you can get it out of the database correctly with any other tools - maybe it's just broken in the database...