# Blob information modified when retrieving image from DB using plain JDBC

Tags: java, image-processing, jdbc, db2, blob

I am working on a small POC (which will be integrated into a bigger application) which consists of

**Problem Context**

1. reading an image in a simple java application program,
2. Convert image into a byte array `byte[] imageEncodedBytes = baos.toByteArray()`
3. storing it into a remote DB2 database (technology used was not imp, so I am using plain jdbc for now)
4. Reading it back from the DB and
5. converting it back to ensure that the re-creation of the image works. ( I am able to open the new re-created image in any image viewer)

**Issues**

The issues occur at step 5.

1. I read the image using a select query into a Result Set.
2. use the `rs.getBlob("ColumnName")` to get the blob value.
3. Fetch the byte array from the blob value using `byte[] decodedArray = myBlob.getBytes(1, (int)myBlob.length())`
4. Create the image from the obtained byte array.

At Step 3 the byte array `decodedArray` obtained from the blob differs from the byte array 'imageEncodedBytes' that I get when I read the image. 
As a consequence, the following code to create the image from the byte array `decodedArray` fails.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedArray);
//Writing to image
BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(bais); // Line of failure. No registered provider able to read bais
ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"snap.jpg"));
```

**References and Other data for issue investigation**

I have referred the following links for verification 
1. [Inserting image in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311648/how-to-insert-image-as-blob-in-db-2)
2. [This Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112197/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-im-null) offers insight, but yet I was not able to determine,  how to register the `ImageReader`.
4. When inserting the image to DB2 I am using - the following query

```
 Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PHOTO (ID,PHOTO_NM,PHOTO_IM, THMBNL_IM) " + "VALUES (1,'blob("+bl+")',blob('"+bl+"')")
```

5. As an alternative to fetching blob value from the result set I have also used `binaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream("PHOTO_IM")` to get the binary stream and then get byte array from the binary stream. even in this case, the decodedArray is different from imageEncodedBytes

Please assist, I may be missing something extremely trivial here, but I am not able to figure out what. Any help/pointers will be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using `PreparedStatement` when inserting data.

Comment: @mustaccio,  Thanks for responding. I tried that, but to no avail. That still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution is sort of a workaround that I have worked on.

I have used the jdbcTemplates to resolve the issue. The lobHandler Object of the jdbc template provides an easy way to manage the blobs.

Steps to resolve using the Spring Lob Handler

1. ) Created a Data Source
2. ) configured the Jdbc template to use the data source
3. ) use the lobHandler code to execute the insert query

Code below

```
 jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO PHOTO (PHOTO_IM) VALUES (?)",
                      new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobHandler) {                         
                              protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) {                                                    
                              try {
                                 lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 1, bean.getImageOrig(), bean.getImageLength());                               
                                } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }     

                              }

                          }
                );
```

references 
1. ) [Stack Overflow Link - Spring JDBC Template Insert Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770877/spring-jdbctemplate-insert-blob-and-return-generated-key)
2. ) [Stack Overflow Link - Close InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946849/close-java-inputstream-after-pass-to-spring-jdbc-lobhandler)
3. ) [Spring Doc for LobHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler.html)